# Android device reboots occasionally

Tags: android, debugging

We are testing our Android app on real-world devices and notice some of them reboot occasionally after 2-3 hours of app running. The app consists of one service with 3 threads (with GPS and network) and two activities, one of wich is resource-consuming (displays the map)

Logcat did not help, as we did not see any important messages before the device reboots. Sometimes the device even does not start, only battery removal helps to start it again.

The devices are based on different hardware, produced in different countries (mostly PRC, hehe) and use different Android versions.

What are the most common problems that could lead to device reboot and how does one debug it?

Comment: 10 months later, did you find out what was causing it after all?

Comment: It seems that some devices got overheat when using GPS for more then an hour or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely an overheating problem when GPS receiver is on. Turning GPS off and getting location from cell network, the app keeps running smoothly for hours.

Thanks everyone for the responses and ideas!

Answer (score 4):

There're two kinds of reboot in Android:

1. System server fault. In that case no reboot happens but `Zygote` restarts instead. Common reasons:

   - Watchdog killed a system_server process because of deadlock in of services it's running.
   - Fatal exception occured in one of system services. However, the actual reason sometimes may be a hardware issue. For example, in some cases after factory reset `ext2` partitions aren't formatted as follows. It leads to errors and `/data/` partition is mounted as read-only, which produces a bunch of errors.
   - In rare cases watchdog can be timed out because of high memory and CPU usage.

   Both are quite rare and can be reproduced mostly in monkey-testing, not real-case scenarios. You may see an example of logcat output by killing the `service_manager` process with `adb shell`.
2. Kernel panic. In that case device actually reboots. As kernel panic happens on the layer beyound Android, it won't produce any logcat output. Instead it'll write a stack trace into console. You may read it from `/dev/kmsg` or from ADB shell: `adb shell dmesg`.

   Unfortunately it's hard to read those as on most devices console output is disabled and `kmsg` buffer will be erased on each reboot.

P.S. Also reboot may be caused by hardware issues. In that case it's unlikely to find any traces but hopefully this should be reproduced only on particular devices.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. I think that if the root of the problem is in Zygote then we should see some log messages. As soon as I don't remember any, that might be a KP. Anyway we will try killing service_manager and watch the difference in logs.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (also  gps and network)  I have forgoten to set the network update timer to production (15 minutes)  so the device  updated every 15 seconds  any way the device  overheated  soner or later (htc desire)
Try to  minimize the cpu usage ( profiling)  or  ensure a proper cooling mechanism

Comment: Yes we do very heavy netowrking in debug/test, plus the GPS receiver consumes a lot of power and heats up a lot. But the rebooting devices are a bit colder then the stable ones. My Nuvifone with 2.1, Xperia with 2.x cyanogen, Iconia with 4.0 and several chineese noname devices with 2.1, 2.2, 2.3.x and 4.x work great, though they get extremely hot (my Nuvifone is ready to make some coffee). Anyway, CPU usage is normal, moslty GPS access heats up.

Comment: the device can be cooler from the outside  but is hotter in the inside also   if I understand you correctly a device from a differen vendor can have a different  critiacl temparature  try it out  turn of the loging and minimize network communication it will work

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have provided, it sounds like you are most likely leaking a `Thread`. You can use DDMS to analyze [thread usage](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#thread) over your app's course of execution. Another possibility is that you are simply just running out of memory... you can also use DDMS to help you out with this.

Comment: Thanks. But why does not the service and/or activity get killed and GC'ed?

Comment: Services are long-term processes that exist even after the application stops running... so you need to unregister them when necessary. The Activity's aren't GC'd because the underlying Android system will destroy the Activitys when the device is running low on resources.

Comment: If, as You noticed, "...simply running out of memory", the Activities *will* be killed, destroyed, and memory freed, but it does not happen. Services are not killed either (though they can be killed), and, BTW, the service and activities share the same Application object. So I'm not shure it's a low-memory problem (however, this could be a bug in OEM andrid build?)

Comment: Update: it seems that turning off USB debugging helps a bit - the app runs twice longer. BTW, we are doing a lot of logging, could it affect?

Comment: Interesting observation. I also have long-term stability problems while logging / debugging and occasionally the phone decides to lock up or do a reset. Sometimes cached corrupted files of other applications are in the way and the only solution is wiping the cache partition in system service mode. Android debugging can be a fragile thing.

Comment: @NobuGames `Log` can drain your battery sometimes... but unless you have a `while(true) Log.v("asdf")` loop somewhere, I don't think it would escalate to the point where your device runs out of RAM. It sounds like a memory leak to me... your goal should be to *find* the memory leak and get rid of it... not find trivial ways to lessen the impact of the memory leak :)

Comment: Or as the answer above notes... it might be an over-heating problem as well.

Comment: Okay, thanks. On moday we will take a closer look at what DDMS offers for threads and memleaks, then turn off heavy logging (we additionally log something to a file on sdcard).